Closed sets definition in complex analysis
Here's the translation:
Are limit points and boundary points the same? If not, why are there two versions of the definition for a closed set? Which one is correct?

A set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$  is said to be closed if $A$ contains all its limit points.
A set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ is said to be closed if $A$ contains all its boundary points.


Please don't yell.

@Sammy Black : your too short remark is not understandable : it is about the fact that capital letters is some countries are considered as "shouting" but in other countries like mine (France) it isn't considered so...

Neither is more correct since we can prove:

A set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ contains all its limit points if and only if it contains all its boundary points.

However, the first definition is more common as a starting point.

See this article as well, particularly the Venn diagram involving the relationship between a set, its limit points, and its boundary points.
